# gdb prints output (stdout) to RGui console instead of gdb console on Windows when debugging C++ code

Tags: c++, r, gdb, rcpp, rgui

I am debugging a C++ shared library (DLL) of an `R` library that uses the `Rcpp` framework.

I am on Windows and use `gdb` for debugging (the version installed via the `Rtools`).

I start debugging via the recommended command:

`gdb Rgui.exe --silent`

My problem: It seems that `RGui` captures all output created by `Rcpp` and `R` "print" functions in `gdb` to `stdout` and shows it in the `RGui` R console instead of the `gdb` console (terminal):

```
(gdb) call dbg_print(df)
```

[image]

**How can I "redirect" the output to the `gdb` console?**

PS 1: I could not find a setting for this in the RGui preferences

PS 2: Here is the code of the `dbg_print` function:

```
void dbg_print(DataFrame df) {
  Rcpp::print(df);
}

// Calls R's print function:
// inline void print(SEXP s) {
//    Rf_PrintValue(s);           // defined in Rinternals.h
// }
```

See also the [source code for `Rf_PrintValue` in core R](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/9b732e3338ed0f618ba18d136a68ca68733de3ef/src/main/print.c):

**Edit 1:** `Rgui.exe` does not offer an obvious switch for output redirection:

[image]

**Edit 2:** I am quite sure that [R prints to stdout](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/9b732e3338ed0f618ba18d136a68ca68733de3ef/src/main/printutils.c)

> All printing in R is done via the functions Rprintf and REprintf [...]
>
> Rprintf writes to standard output. It is redirected by the sink()
>   function, and is suitable for ordinary output.
>
> REprintf writes to
>   standard error and is useful for error messages and warnings. It is
>   not redirected by sink().

**Edit 3:** @duckmayr has pointed me to an [R callback function (in C) called R_WriteConsole](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/9b732e3338ed0f618ba18d136a68ca68733de3ef/src/unix/system.txt) that could be used to register my own printing routine to redirect R output to the `gdb` console (stdout). I am looking for more example code [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51242993/difference-between-r-3-4-4-and-r-3-5-1-in-r-api-for-c)...

Comment: Although this will not solve your problem directly, sections 1.3.1, 1.6, 6.5, and 8.1.2 of [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) may provide some helpful information

Comment: @duckmayr Interesting! I see two possible way: `sinks` (*[...] Rprintf [...] is used in exactly the same way as printf, but is guaranteed to write to R’s output (which might be a GUI console rather than a file, and can be re-directed by sink)*) and [registering a callback](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Setting-R-callbacks) to capture the written output (eg. `R_WriteConsoleEx`) and redirect it to `gdb` (but ensuring safe unregistering to avoid dangling pointers could be difficult)

Comment: @duckmayr OK, on Windows I see no way to change the callback of `R_WriteConsole[Ex]` (I have analyzed the Rgui source code and [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Setting-R-callbacks) says: *For **Unix-alikes** there is a public header file Rinterface.h that makes it possible to change the standard callbacks*). Any more ideas?